# Error when using jquery hover

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

I have a simple code:

```
<div class="results">
   <ul id="nav">
      <li>
         <table>
           <tr>
             <td><h3>name</h3></td>
           </tr>
         </table> 
      </li>  
   </ul>
</div>
```

And jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#nav li table tr td h3").hover(function() {
      alert('no error');
   });
});
```

When i hover on h3 tag, result no alert(), how to fix it ?

Comment: I copied it directly to jsfiddle and it worked. http://jsfiddle.net/grc4/m6RYC/

Comment: What browser are you using? Worked fine for me in FF3, Chrome and IE6.

Comment: Seems to be ok. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/zp6kP/. First, you have not mentioned which browser are you using and jquery version. Second, I think you load jquery library incorrectly (wrong path, name, etc).

Comment: You don't need all the descendants like `$("#nav li table tr td h3")`. A simple `$('#nav h3')` should work and you'll improve performance

Comment: Check path to jquery library. For example, use firebug plugin for firefox browser. Check the code of jquery to be loaded.

Comment: And you can forget about IE6 compatibility. IE6 is not used any more (too small audience).

Comment: check if you have linked jquery file properly..

Answer (score 0):

You might be using an old version of jQuery or not including it correctly. Try using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine...May be the jquery file attachment issue...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```